# Error in Eclipse Luna: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/HookConfigurator

Tags: osgi, aspectj

I write project work with osgi + aspectj. It work ok in Eclipse Kepler, but when I upgrade to eclipse 4.4 (Luna) then get error:

I open org.eclipse.osgi*.jar found in Eclipse Kepler and see class org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookConfigurator

But in Luna not found.

```
!SESSION 2014-07-16 09:40:14.127 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_45
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-07-16 09:40:14.480
!MESSAGE error loading hook: org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hooks.WeavingHook
!STACK 0
```

Full Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/HookConfigurator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hookregistry.HookRegistry.loadConfigurators(HookRegistry.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hookregistry.HookRegistry.initialize(HookRegistry.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.HookConfigurator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 38 more
[org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj] info Starting AspectJ weaving service ...
-----------------------
Before execution sum
Value =200
-----------------------
Value =200
-----------------------
Value =200.0
[org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.caching.j9] warning cannot start J9 caching service
[org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.caching] info starting standard caching service ...
osgi>
```

I have followed the instructions [here](http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/6864/osgi-and-aspectj-integration), it's based on Eclipse Kepler, but I use Eclipse Luna.
Please help me.

Comment: Could this one help?: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1001969-error-loading-hook--org-eclipse-equinox-weaving-hooks-weavinghook?comment=402997013#/activity/ticket:

Comment: Is the stack trace really that short. If not then the complete trace might help.

Comment: I edited my post, with full stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

Equinox Luna has change many of the internal details that require all equinox framework hook implementations to be migrated to use the new hooks.  It is unclear to me what you have installed that is trying to implement HookConfigurator from the stacktrace.  If it is the Equinox weaving support which supports weaving with aspectj then you will need the Equinox weaving bundles released with the Equinox 4.4 (luna) release as well.

If not then what ever framework extension you have installed that does weaving will need to be migrated to the new Equinox framework specific hooks in luna.